# Managing permission if there is a list that have different permission than its site collection

Tags: 2013, list, permissions, groups

I have the following:-

- Team site collection. With the following general permissions:-

  - "All users" can read
  - Managers can contribute
- Then I wanted to add a “Contact Us” list of type issue tracking. Where all users can add items, and Managers can approve.

So since my list is having different permission from its site collection (users can Edit inside the list, but can only Read inside the site collection), so I went to the list permission and I stop inheriting permission from the site collection. And I grant "All users" to be able to add items inside the list. And everything went well.

But users who want to add pictures inside the list items, will get the following error (of course they can save the item ,, but they can not add images to it):-

[image]

The problem I think is that "All Users" does not have edit permission on the “site assets” folder which stores the images, as follow:-

[image]

So I am thinking of the following:-

- To create a new sub site, inside the current site collection. Which allow "all users" to add, so that they will be able to add items inside the sub site’s “Site Assets” folder.
- And then to move the list from being inside the site collection to be inside my new sub site?

So can anyone advice on my problem, and the approach I want to follow?

Comment: Or you can create another Document Library/Picture Library and give "All Users" rights to add/edit items in that library and ask users to select that Library while adding pictures ?

Comment: what is the risk to give user edit permission on site assets library?

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri the problem is that i can not control the "Destination Library" drop down options, inside the "upload Image" dialog, or to specify the default selection. so informing the user to select specific destination library is not an easy approach for end users. while if i create a new sub-site it will have a separate "Site Asset" folder, which i can grant "All User" Edit permission on it... what do u think? –

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Site Asset Library contains other folders that have information that should not be edited/deleted by "All Users".. –